# gspread - Getting values as string from numeric like column

Tags: python, gspread

I am trying to read a google sheet using python using the gspread library.

The initial authentication settings is done and I am able to read the respective sheet.

However when I do

```
sheet.get_all_records()
```

The column containing numeric like values (eg. 0001,0002,1000) are converted as numeric field. That is the leading zeroes are truncated. How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I hope this helps : https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/231

Comment: The solution that the have mentioned is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? In this answer, as one of several workarounds, `get_all_values()` is used instead of `get_all_records()`. After the values are retrieved, the array is converted to the list. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

```
values = worksheet.get_all_values()
head = values.pop(0)
result = [{head[i]: col for i, col in enumerate(row)} for row in values]
```

#### Reference:

- [get_all_values()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_all_records#gspread.models.Worksheet.get_all_values)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. Atleast my purpose is solved

Comment: @Jithin P James Thank you for replying. At gspread, I think that this workaround can be used. But I apologize that I couldn't propose the direct solution for resolving your issue.

Comment: @Tannaike - I have raised this issue in github, hopefully it will be fixed. 
https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/598#issuecomment-542177794

Comment: @Jithin P James Thank you for replying. `get_all_records()` retrieves the values using `get_all_values()`. The retrieved data is converted to the number with `int()` in the function of `numericise()`. By this, `0001` is converted to `1`. So for example, when `value = int(value)` is modified to `value = value if type(value) is str else int(value)` at [this line](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/6970ca80371470bdf69979a49681747a22c07465/gspread/utils.py#L76), your goal can be achieved. But I'm not sure whether this modification is useful for other users. So I couldn't propose this.

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent gspread from casting values to int passing the [numericise_ignore](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get_all_records) parameter to the get_all_records() method.

You can disable it for a specific list of indices in the row:

```
# Disable casting for columns 1, 2 and 4 (1 indexed):
sheet.get_all_records(numericise_ignore=[1, 2, 4])
```

Or, disable it for the whole row values with numericise_ignore set to *'all'* :

```
sheet.get_all_records(numericise_ignore=['all'])
```